# Kotkin error java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

Tags: api, kotlin

I'm a bit new to Kotlin. How can I resolve this error. please someone help me
`Error:java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $`

[image: The api's response]

[image: Retrofit interface]

[image: The data class I'm using]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

It's because the payload is an object instead of an array of objects. So remove List from your retrofit method return type.

So go to your retrofit interface and change the return type o that method from
`List<NasaModels>`

to
`NasaModels`